# R dataframe: combine conditions by processing

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to find all columns with all `NA`-values. If there are not all `NA`-values in column, I have to replace `NA`s with `0`.
My solution is:

```
NA_check <- colSums(is.na(frame)) == nrow(frame) #True or False - all NA or not

frame[is.na(frame) & which(names(frame) %in% names(NA_check)[which(NA_check == FALSE, arr.ind=T)])] <- 0
```

These conditions work separately, but they don't work together or I get some errors combining them. How can I solve my problem?

P.S. This modification also doesn't work if `NA_check`is not all `FALSE`:

```
frame[is.na(frame[which(names(frame) %in% names(NA_check)[which(NA_check == FALSE, arr.ind=T)])])] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out columns which has atleast one non-`NA` value (not all values are `NA`) and replace `NA` in that subset to 0.

```
not_all_NA <- colSums(!is.na(frame)) > 0
frame[not_all_NA][is.na(frame[not_all_NA])] <- 0
```

We can check this with an example :

```
frame <- data.frame(a = c(NA, NA, 3, 4), b = NA, c = c(NA, 1:3), d = NA)
frame
#   a  b  c  d
#1 NA NA NA NA
#2 NA NA  1 NA
#3  3 NA  2 NA
#4  4 NA  3 NA
not_all_NA <- colSums(!is.na(frame)) > 0
frame[not_all_NA][is.na(frame[not_all_NA])] <- 0
frame

#  a  b c  d
#1 0 NA 0 NA
#2 0 NA 1 NA
#3 3 NA 2 NA
#4 4 NA 3 NA
```

---

We can also do this with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
frame %>% mutate(across(where(~any(!is.na(.))), tidyr::replace_na, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the task was replace `NA`, then the column is NOT entirely composed of `NA`.
I checked your solution and got `undefined columns selected` error :(

Comment: Ok...so need to invert the condition. I have updated the answer and included an example to show how it works. Can you confirm if that is what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error using your solution `undefined columns selected` in `frame[not_all_NA][is.na(frame[not_all_NA])] <- 0`

Comment: @Angelika Please provide an example similar to as I have shown using which we can reproduce the error that you are facing.